# Receber dados em várias linhas

Tags: python

Eu preciso criar um código que vai calcular a media, variância e desvio padrão dos dados digitados pelo usuário.

Eu pensei em jogar esses dados em uma lista e a partir de então trabalhá-los. Porém, o usuário irá digitar cada número em uma linha. Capturar esses dados, cada um em uma linha, em uma lista está sendo minha dificuldade.
Tentei trabalhar com o módulo sys e colocar um laço dentro do sys.stdin:

```
for n in sys.stdin:
     for x in range(n):
          lista.append(n)
```

Mas eu tive alguns erros.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Não quero necessariamente trabalhar com o módulo sys, apenas foi uma ideia.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isabela, o erro provavelmente existe porque esse método geralmente deixa uma linha vazia depois de encerrado, o que pode estragar operações matemáticas. Tente adicionar `x.rstrip()` ao código e veja se isso soluciona.

Outro método é usando o fileinput:

```
import fileinput

for x in fileinput.input():
    lista.append(x)
```

O fileinput também tem a mesma questão da linha em branco, então o `x.rstrip()` também se faria necessário.

Caso precise usar uma melhor estrutura de dados mais pra frente, sugiro dar uma olhada na lib Pandas.

Comment: Obrigada, Rodrigo. :)